# z3 SMT solver: unknown result after running QF_BVRE benchmark

Tags: z3, smt

I just downloaded the benchmarks for seq and regexp sorts (using z3-4.3.2). What could be the problem when I get unknown as result after running "membership_1.smt2"?

I did not specify any further command line options. According to the benchmark it should result in sat, but unknown is printed without any model.

Thank you

**edit:**

I noticed further, that "re-begin" is not recognized. Has this to do with the version of z3 or did u just forgot a command line option?

Comment: You are right, the command "re-begin" is not recognized and the command "re-concat" is not recognized too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't know where the OP or commenter found the "membership_1.smt2" example input.  I checked the [SMT-LIB benchmarks](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/benchmarks.shtml), and the source of Z3, S3, and Z3-str, and couldn't find it.

In any case, the problem was that the OP was testing a benchmark written either for [S3](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~trinhmt/S3/) or [Z3-str](https://github.com/z3str/Z3-str) and running it against an unmodified version of Z3.  S3 and Z3-str require a modified version of Z3 to handle these extensions.  This is described on the S3 website [S3: A Symbolic String Solver for Web Security Analysis, http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~trinhmt/S3/, accessed Aug. 4, 2016]:

> Modified Version of Z3 Solver
>
> - The source code of the modified Z3 is available [here](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~trinhmt/S3/z3-source-060115.zip).
> - We modify Z3 to have the interaction between String theory and Arithmetic theory.
> - These newly-added API methods allows us to query the length of a string variable, and relationship between the length of different
>     string variables, as shown in [our CCS'14 paper](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~trinhmt/S3/ccs14-trinh.pdf).
> - Our modified version of Z3 is also used by [Z3-str GROUP](https://sites.google.com/site/z3strsolver/download) for [integer/string theory integration](https://sites.google.com/site/z3strsolver/acknowledgement).

Grepping the [(unmodified) Z3 source](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) shows no matches for "re-begin" or "re-concat".  Grepping the modified version shows that these tokes are defined in `lib/seq_decl_plugin.cpp` of [`z3-source-060115.zip`](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~trinhmt/S3/z3-source-060115.zip).